# I cannot move the items freely on layouts in Xamarin Android

Tags: layout, xamarin.android, controls, toolbox

I can drag and drop items but I cannot change the position of items on layouts in Xamarin

Answer (score 0):

If you use linear layout, items will be snapped to the grid. For a free moving, change the layout to a relative.

Comment: Even if it is relative layout I cannot move freely

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin does not support drag and drop.
You can only drag and drop a component from the toolbar to add it to layout.

You need to manually set the position of the component​ if you use frame or relative layout.

If you use linear layout component are added one by one horizontally or vertically​.